# how we make image file dynamic in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var file = $("#imgstep"+id)[0].files[0];
var fileName = file.name;
var fileSize = file.size;
```

I have problem to get multile files name in one function. The first time  this will get file name but other time this will get error on

```
var file = $("#imgstep"+id)[0].files[0];
```

and show cannot read property 'files' of undefined.

Comment: Means that `$("#imgstep"+id)[0]` found no elements. You need to show more code.